# Google Directions Api on driving bus mode

Tags: google-maps-api-3, bus, driving-directions

I would like to use Google Directions Api on 'DRIVING' mode, but I want to know the best route driving a bus and not a car.
I'm not talking about 'TRANSIT' mode. I don't want to take a bus but drive it.

Does anybody know if that option is possible?

Comment: That functionality is not currently present in the Google Directions API.

Answer (score 1):

As geocodezip mentioned in the comments, that functionality is just not possible.

If you choose to set the mode property within the Direction Service API to 'DRIVING', GM will assume you want standard driving directions for a motor vehicle (car).

Here's an extract from their documentation concerning possible travel modes for the Directions Service API:

> The following travel modes are currently supported:
>
> - **DRIVING (Default)** standard driving directions using the road network.
> - **BICYCLING** bicycling directions via bicycle paths & preferred streets.
> - **TRANSIT** directions via public transit routes.
> - **WALKING** walking directions via pedestrian paths & sidewalks.

So to answer your question. **No, unlike the TRANSIT option, there's no way to specify a form of vehicle you would like to use within the 'DRIVING' option of the Direction Service API**.
But that might change one day.